# Object to String Conversion Issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a JQuery that records all the immediate parent lists when a child list is clicked.

**Example -**

```
- Parent1  
  - Child1
     - GrandChild1
     - Grandchild2
     - Grandchild3
  - Child2
     - Grandchild4
     - Grandchild5
```

Clicking on Grandchild2 will record Parent1, Child1 and Grandchild2.

I want to use JQuery, JS and Cookies to print a value in another page when something is clicked in this list page. However the following codes doesn't work. Kindly help.

**JQUERY and JS Code -** (for the list page)

```
function objToString (obj) {
            var str = '';
            for (var p in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    str += p + '::' + obj[p] + '\n';
                }
            }
            return str;
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('li').click(function() {
                var obj = $(this).parents('li').add(this);
                obj.css('color', 'red');
                var data= "data=";
                document.cookie = data+objToString(obj);
            });
        });
```

**PHP Code -** (for the page where the list data is to be printed)

```
echo $_COOKIE['data'];
```

The PHP Code should print `Parent1 Child1 Grandchild2` for the above example. Also all functionalities should be IE 7 compatible. Only problem I face is that `objToString` doesn't work properly here.

Comment: You're defining `$obj` but sending `obj` to the `objToString` method.

Comment: why aren't you using `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @Jason P >> Following your advice it prints now `0::[object HTMLLIElement]`. Still not printing the required result.

Comment: @Markasoftware >> Thanks for your reply. I never heard of `JSON.stringify`. Can you please elaborate this example with it?

Comment: `JSON` is an object stringification system used to turn objects and other variables into strings

Comment: I just now came to know that `JSON.stringify` doesn't work on IE7.

Comment: you need IE7 support? In that case, use `json2.js`, which emulates it

Comment: @Markasoftware>> Just tried it.It doesn't works. What is wrong with my `objToString` method?

Comment: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js is where you can get json2.js and what do you mean it doesn't work? Also, you shouldn't use `objToString` because PHP also has a built in `json_decode` function that can parse stringified JSON. And JSON is just the "right" and "standard" way to do this

Comment: Yes, I copied those only beforehand. It says `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON directory.php:46
(anonymous function) directory.php:46
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle`. I included the script as `script src="json2.js"></script>`.

Comment: @Markasoftware doesn't just emulate it, it's the library that browsers adopted to implement it natively

Comment: why would you ever need to put DOM nodes in a cookie? Seems like you should explain use case first...then work on solutions from there. Some sample html would help also. Sounds like AJAX would be better fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON.stringify instead. This function converts any Object to String, concatinating the keys and values.

Example:-

```
var obj = {a:"b", f:{c:"d"},e:"e"};
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Output:-

"{"a":"b","f":{"c":"d"},"e":"e"}"  .

Comment: I used `document.cookie = data+JSON.stringify(obj);` but it says `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON directory.php:76
(anonymous function) directory.php:76
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle` at the Java console.  I included the script as `<script src="json2.js"></script>`

Comment: This might get some issue with HTML Nodes, like if you are doing some thing like.

JSON.stringify($('div'));

This will get Circular Referance error.

Comment: I have edited the code a bit. I have defined the object as `obj` now. `document.cookie = data+JSON.stringify(obj);` still shows no luck. Any guess what to do now?

Comment: The Circular structure error.. comes.. due to the following reason.. as HTML Nodes have circular references.

Since every node has a property 'ownerDocument', which means every node is referring to the document and document node refers to this node via child relation ship.

So it islike    node->document-> node.
This is a very basic case, in case event listeners there can be multiple loops.

Comment: Simple example of Circular Reference:

    var a = {};
    a.b = a;
    JSON.stringify(a);


This will give the same error as you are getting inyour case.

Comment: You should work on this:-

var obj = $(this).parents('li').add(this);
                obj.css('color', 'red');

Comment: If you just want the concatenated tags names, why are you storing the complete tag.
Just store the tag names in the Object.

Comment: Okay, I couldn't get this - "If you just want the concatenated tags names, why are you storing the complete tag. Just store the tag names in the Object"

Comment: How to store _only_ tag names?? Is it this - `var obj = $(this).parents('li').data('li').add(this);`?

Comment: Can you give me a fiddle of what your are doing.. so that I can fix that fiddle can give it back to you

Comment: I finally got the right way to do it, that too without JSON. Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8XU85/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/447yE/6/ Sorry ws busy ... check this out..I guess i did what you want

Comment: I am assuming your HTML structure remains the same.

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much of what I wanted.

Comment: Since I dont know the big picture of what your doing, so before using it, test the implementation for the cases that may come in your implementation.

Comment: Ya, sure. I am making a directory listing of the server files and folders in folder view and your solution does work fine till now.